# How do I get this cartridge out of the faucet?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

The videos I looked at online of other taps shows a way to expose the nut but this cartidge is buried deep in the handle and you can't access any nut if there is one (I'm not sure there is a nut at all). Do I just pull it out using brute force?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have the gland nut off and the seal may be expanded making it difficult to pull the cartridge out without using a small hook and pulling the seal out then the cartridge.

Comment: Just so we're clear, you've turned off the hot And cold water to this, right?  ;-)